# Is there a built-in constant for scala.xml.Text("") in scala?

Tags: xml, scala

I often use it, and I know I can define one for myself in every project. But I want to know if there is one already defined in scala library.

Comment: I am just wondering why you use it "often". If you have a `Node` that  contains no text, you just say `val x=<div></div>`, and the value of `x.child` is empty, it does not contain a `xml.Text` element. Please add some details about your use case, some code will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scala.xml.NodeSeq.empty`, which is a completely empty block of XML rather than an empty `Text` node. Here's a contrived example:

```
import scala.xml._

case class Person(val name: Option[String])

def renderPerson(person: Person) =
  person.name match {
    case Some(name) => <div>{ name }</div>
    case None       => NodeSeq.empty
  }
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any, and the most plausible cause is the one provided by xiefei in comment.